# When multiple conditions are using index condition in sql, combine them(using or operator) together, would it still be performant?

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance

We have a system, which are using rails and mongoid, in the system post can have comments,
and comments can have any nested level,
so I use nested set to implement it,
then post's top level comments need to be paginated,
let's say

```
comments=post.comments.page(1).per(10)
```

assuming the first page comments is comment1,comment2,..comment10,
then I want all those's descendants

```
all_comments=Comment.where(:lft.gte => comment1.lft, :lft.lte => comment1.rgt)
.or(Comment.where(:lft.gte => comment2.lft, :lft.lte => comment2.rgt) ...
.or(Comment.where(:lft.gte => comment10.lft, :lft.lte => comment10.rgt)
```

each part it will use index scan,but oring them together,will it still be performant? (it means Comment.where(cond1).or(cond2).or(cond3), and each part is using index).

the sql would look like

```
select * from comments WHERE (lft >= 10 and lft<=20 OR lft >= 30 and lft<=40 OR...)
```

the explain looks like this

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on comments  (cost=12.55..23.20 rows=9 width=100)
   Recheck Cond: (((lft >= 1) AND (lft <= 8)) OR ((lft >= 9) AND (lft <= 16)) OR ((lft >= 17) AND (lft <= 24)))
   ->  BitmapOr  (cost=12.55..12.55 rows=9 width=0)
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_comments_on_lft  (cost=0.00..4.18 rows=3 width=0)
               Index Cond: ((lft >= 1) AND (lft <= 8))
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_comments_on_lft  (cost=0.00..4.18 rows=3 width=0)
               Index Cond: ((lft >= 9) AND (lft <= 16))
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_comments_on_lft  (cost=0.00..4.18 rows=3 width=0)
               Index Cond: ((lft >= 17) AND (lft <= 24))
(9 rows)
```

Comment: What does the explain output say? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html

Comment: too long to type in here, paste it in original question

Comment: @femto - that's the default expectation when you're asked to provide more details in the comments - you should take it as a prompt to *update your question* rather than leaving important details only in the comments.

Comment: Better use explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) to get not just the plan, but also the results from the execution of the plan. By the way, it looks like you're using an empty table, that will always be fast

Comment: for tree like structure, it would be wise to take a look into recursive CTE

Comment: That type of BitmapOr *can* be performant.  But why ask us?  You have the query.  How long did it take it to run?